# Niven’s theorem proof.

Tags: trigonometry, rational-numbers, rational-functions

I couldn’t find any proof on the internet.
I would appreciate an elementary proof , but any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Niven's_Theorem

Comment: @IamBack do you what page is it in?

Comment: See the link, it has the proof

Comment: @IamBack I don’t understand it..

Comment: @David.S I advise editing your answer into a discussion of that proof (since unlike Robert Israel's it's strictly elementary), so you can tell us at what points you can't understand it. Then we can help with those.

Answer (score 7):

A non-elementary proof goes like this.  Suppose $r$ is rational.  Then $\exp(\pm i\pi r)$ are roots of unity, therefore algebraic integers, and since the algebraic integers form a ring, $2\sin(\pi r) = i  \exp(-i\pi r) - i \exp(i\pi r)$ is an algebraic integer.  But the only algebraic integers that are rational are ordinary integers.  Thus the only cases where
$r$ and $\sin(\pi r)$ are both rational is where $2 \sin(\pi r)$ is an integer (and that integer can only be $0$, $\pm 1$ or $\pm 2$).

EDIT: Unpacked a little, the proof goes like this.  It's slightly more convenient to use $\cos$ instead of $\sin$, but $\cos(\theta) = \sin(\theta + \pi/2)$, so this is equivalent.  Suppose $r= m/n$ (in lowest terms) is rational, and let 
$w = \exp(i \pi r) = \cos(\pi r) + i \sin(\pi r)$.  By de Moivre's theorem we have 
$w^{2n} = (\cos(\pi r) + i \sin(\pi r))^{2n} = \exp(2 i \pi m)= 1$, i.e.
$w$ is a root of the polynomial $X^n - 1$,  and similarly
$\overline{w} = \exp(-i\pi r)$ is also a root of $X^n - 1$.  Thus $w$ and $\overline{w}$ are eigenvalues of the $n \times n$ matrix
$$ M = \pmatrix{0 & \ldots & 0 & 1\cr
            1 & \ldots & 0 & 0\cr
            \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\cr
            0 & \ldots & 1 & 0\cr} $$
(i.e. the matrix with $1$ in the top right corner and just below the main diagonal, and $0$ everywhere else).  Let $u$ and $v$ be eigenvectors of this matrix for $w$ and $\overline{w}$ respectively.  Consider the $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix
$$ A = (M \otimes I) + (I \otimes M)$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.  Then $u \otimes v$ is an eigenvector
of $A$ for eigenvalue $w + \overline{w}  = 2 \cos(\pi r)$, i.e.
$$A (u \otimes v) = (M u \otimes v) + (u \otimes Mv) = w (u \otimes v) + \overline{w} (u \otimes v) = (w + \overline{w})(u \otimes v) $$
So $2 \cos(\pi r)$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is a monic polynomial $P(X) = X^{n^2} + \sum_{j=0}^{n^2-1} c_j X^j$ with integer coefficients.  But if $x$ is a rational number with denominator $d > 1$ (in lowest terms), $P(x)$ has denominator $d^{n^2}$ and is not an integer.  Therefore the only cases where $r$ and $\cos(\pi r)$ are both rational are when $2 \cos(\pi r)$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Another elementary proof follows from section 3 of this article by Joerg Jahnel.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/JahnelCosineRational.pdf

Here Jahnel proves that the only rational values for $\cos(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is rational are $\{-1, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$, and one can use the identity that $\sin(\alpha) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha)$ to deduce Niven's theorem.